# Firebase: how to check client side session with php server side script

Tags: php, session, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I'm authenticating client side throught Firebase SDK the users to my app.
A clientside session is then started. I want the user then to be able to post to PHP endpoints some data. I want the PHP script to check if the request is coming from a authenticated user and then validate the rest of the data. If everything is ok, we finalize the operation.

I thought to do it like this:

- User is authenticated client side
- On Auth event a request for a JWT token with the user id in it is issued client side via ajax to a dedicated PHP script. Once the token is generated it is stored in a session cookie.
- The form submit will carry the JWT token and the endpoint will decode the token and check if the uid stored in it is a valid user id registered in the Firebase DB.

Good or terrible idea from a security point of view?

Comment: If you're using the `uid` from Firebase's auth as a user id, you can just use the [JWT associated with the Firebase session](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/getauth.html) instead of creating one yourself.

Comment: True, but certainly I'm missing something: how can I use the token to verify that the user has an active session. I decoded the token and it has only the uid and the iat fields. So I know that it was issued at a certain time but how can I be sure that it is a valid one? Is there such a method to be applied server side through REST interface?

Comment: Depends on your definition of an active session. The JWT itself would be valid for the amount of time specified on your Firebase instance's Login & Auth page. You could verify it by using their REST API to attempt a read/write that only an authenticated user could make.

Answer (score 1):

First rule of thumb is that in order to validate a Firebase-generated JWT, you need the secret to your Firebase. Second rule of thumb is that your Firebase secret should never be sent or stored on a client.

Given that, to validate a JWT via PHP, you will need to use a library which decodes it and verifies it has been signed by your Firebase secret. Once you've verified that, I would look at the JWT's uid and see if it matches the uid of the user who owns the resource.